PAM8403 weird clicking / banging noise
I'm using an ESP32, a PCM5102, and a PAM8403 to output a 3.5mm Audio Jack output.
In my circuit, I'm sending the Audio Signal via I2S to the PCM5102, where a quieter output can be picked up. If the output should be louder, the Signal of the PCM is connected to the PAM8403. However, there I hear a really loud bang/clicking sound all the time.
Here is an audio clip https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iXzqpvoZ2_2qKYD_3bPWyHUqBCelBy6X/
The first seconds are directly over the box (JBL Clip 1) and the last are approximately 10cm away. Even if I turn the Volume of the Box (It has buttons for this) all the way up, I can't hear the noise if listening via the PCM5102, however, it is clearly noticeable via the PAM8403.
At first, I thought it might be the power supply, but after testing this out, I can say it isn't. At the moment everything is running out of 4 AA Batteries in Series.
I'm using Breakout boards / NodeMCU, so no custom PCB. All soldered wired connections.
Any suggestion on how to get rid of the PAM8403 noise is appreciated.

0
It is a low frequency oscillation. They used to call it "motorboating". You may want to see if the sound is present in that amplifier even with the input disconnected.

@gbarry if nothing is connected to the audio input I can hear nothing. However, as soon as there are wires added (floating only connected to the PAM8403, other side unconnected) I hear it again, but quieter as if it would not be floating and connected to the PCM5102.

More capacitance on power supply rails MAY help
